# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

I got an app and imported it successfully into Android Studio. While I am running the app, the tool saying like this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class
```

And finally I am getting *"build failed"*

Can any one help me out from this problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of all `build.gradle` files ? (inside and outside each module)

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it. I used old analytics library with EasyTracker and when I removed it and migrate to a new play-services-analytics 8.1.0 this issue had gone.